# how to increase font size of textfield placed in a subview in ios?

Tags: ios

On the View of my ViewController I have placed another view. On that second view I have put `textFields`. I have set default font size of these textFields as 16. For ipad I set the font size 20 (programatically). While running the app on iPad whenever I tap on the `textField` and type, text is displayed in proper size but as soon as I tap elsewhere font size is reduced to 16.

Code I am using is:

```
[_nameOnCardTxt setFont:[UIFont ipadFont20]];
[_creditCardNotxt setFont:[UIFont ipadFont20]];
```

tried `[[UITextField appearance] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];` too but did'nt work.

Plz tell me how should i write below line of code

```
[[UITextField appearance] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
```

so that it would work for the `textFields` of the `subview`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
     [_nameOnCardTxt setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0]];
```

Use the font you want by replacing the Arial font i used for the sake of example.
For differentiating between iPad and iPhone use:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // Code here for iPad
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
   // Code here for the iPhone
}
```